# How can i execute a command only when there are files in hdfs

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-nifi

I'm working with NiFi and Hive in an HDP snadbox in Ambari.

I have a NiFi flow where i upload modified files to hdfs and then with a generateflowfile, i pass the query `load data inpath 'hdfs/path/' into table tablename` to a puthiveql processor.

It works great but i would like to do that ONLY when there are files in the path specified by 'hdfs/path' because when the command `load inpath` executes, that hdfs directory empties.

I don't know how can i do that.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`ListHDFS`** processor and configure the processor to run frequently(like every minute..etc), **Directory** property value.

- This processor stores the state and incrementally runs and only outputs a flowfile when there are newly added files detected in the directory.

Then use **`ReplaceText`** Processor

- Replacement strategy as **`AlwaysReplace`**
- Replacement value as **`load data inpath '${path}/${filename}' into table tablename`**

Then connect the success relation to **`PutHiveQL`** processor to execute load data command.

***Flow:***

```
1.ListHDFS
2.ReplaceText
3.PutHiveQL
```